# django - add existing ModelAdmin with his inlines to another admin form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i have:

```
class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ TextInline,]

class EventAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

when viewing Event at admin, i want that BookAdmin will be shown at the same form(with his inlines)

is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the point is just to show data from Book you may add Book fields in EventAdmin with __ notation (if the two models have some kind of relation) or just define EventAdmin methods that fetches values from Book and add them as readonly_fields.

Something like this:

```
class EventAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    def book_texts(self, instance):
        out = ''
        for book in instance.books:
            for inline in book.your_other_replated_class:
                out += inline.value_to_print
        return out
    book_text.allow_tags = True

    readonly_fields = [book_texts]
```

Otherwise, if the point is to be able to submit the two forms together, I'll suggest to define a custom Form class and handle the submitted data in a View.

Comment: @EyalCh well ok, the difference stands between showing data and submitting data, If you just need to show something I wouldn't spend time struggling with forms, just make a method in EventAdmin that loops trough each Book's related field and render values.